# how to redirect a request made to url to a specific domain/url in nginx config?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I've a website running on port 80 (http).
And I've configured it in nginx-config file as well.
Now, the website is not opening up directly by giving the url (Example - `http://wap.example.com`).
I've to mention like this - `http://wap.example.com:8000/someurl/` 
in the url to open the website.
I've researched on internet and tried different things to redirect `http://wap.example.com` to `http://wap.example.com/someurl/` which is exactly what I want, so that the user wont bother entering the complete url every time.
My nginx config file -

```
server {
        listen   80; 
        server_name wap.example.com; 

     location / {      
       proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
     }
}
```

I've tried the `return 301` statement as well but it doesnt seems to work as well. A help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding: `location = / { return 301 /someurl/; }`

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith for replying. However, I've tried the same but it loads the `http://example.com/someurl` but says `the page isn't working, wap.example.com redirected you too many times.`

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Tried that as well, but it ends up giving the same `too many redirects` error. Also, I've tried --> `return 301 http://wap.example.com:8000/someurl/`  in config, it works well but it is showing the port 8000 in url which isnt what we require.

Comment: There is no redirect in your nginx configuration. That means it must come from your application.

Comment: Well @MichaelHampton ,  I've rechecked the code.I'm using spring-boot and checked my-controller.There's no redirection code implemented in it.